# Emailing as different domain from our IIS server

Tags: email, iis, windows, .net, spf

We have an enterprisey web application which uses .NET to send out email from our domain (oursite.com).  This domain exists and has a valid SPF record and we've very rarely had spam issues with our clients.  These emails are generally alerts within our system, nothing product or sales related.

We have an offering which administers surveys to our clients' customers.  The system emails these customers (not unsolicited) to let them know there's a survey to take.

One of our clients asked if they can send out using their own email domain (client.com).  I feel like the customers' mail systems may believe this is spam because of the SPF record.

Is there anything I can do on my end to make it authorized (my server send out as client.com)?  I'm not sure if my client would even know how to change the SPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure your client lists your server in their domain's SPF record.
   Your client (or their admin staff/hosting provider/whoever controls their DNS) needs to do this. It can't be done from "your end" unless you control the DNS record in question.
2. Add a `From:` header to the outbound email.
   A `Reply-to:` header would also be nice, but is not necessary.